# mergExt install assistance needed

Tags: livecode

I have the commercial LiveCode license.

I'm trying to install mergJSON as my first external and have looked at the lesson as well as googled all I can. I've got the Externals folder set up and now am hung up on setting up the Runtime structure. Which file goes into which folder in the Runtime folder? There is a mergJSON.bundle, .dll, .dylib, .lcext, and .so. The lesson that is referenced doesn't show a Linux folder under Runtime and it shows the files going into a Database Drivers folder. It also does not help someone new in this environment have a clue which of the 5 mergJSON files goes into which folder under Runtime.

Something as simple as a directory tree under My LiveCode would go a super long way in helping to understand how to get this product installed.

I am on OSX.

Can someone give me some pointers on getting this bundle I purchased loaded to I can use it?

Answer (score 0):

The directory structure for Linux is the same as the other platforms shown in RunRev's [how to](http://lessons.runrev.com/s/lessons/m/4071/l/6347-how-to-install-3rd-party-externals-for-use-in-the-ide-and-standalone-builder) but using the *.so file.

The filetypes for externals are:

- Windows = *.dll
- OS X = *.bundle
- OS X Server = *.dylib
- Linux = *.so
- iOS and Android = *.lcext

This directory mirrors what you will find in the Tools/Runtime directory inside the LiveCode app package as seen here:

[image: runtime folder]